# Where'd this guy get a grenade?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lair-of-the-white-worm

Near the end of *Lair of the White Worm*, archaeologist Angus Flint kills the titular worm by dropping a live grenade into its open mouth. Where could a civilian like him acquire a piece of military hardware like that?

Comment: Black market? James bought it? IRA gave away with free potatoes?

Comment: In the book "Adam" is an explosives expert with military experience. He knows how to handle dynamite and has a revolver in his luggage